# Vertex AI - cannot create managed notebook instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm following all the (easy) steps in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/managed/quickstart-create-console), but I'm stuck at clicking the "CREATE" button. When I click it, the process runs for a few seconds, then the button re-appears, like I never clicked it.

If I go back to the "Managed Notebooks" page, no instance is present.

Am I missing something basic? Has someone the same problem as mine?

Comment: We had some issue with an infrastructure from Wednesday night to Thursday morning PST

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what it was, but today the issue seems resolved!